# Ruby on Rails , functionalities having twitter authentication and email authentication (autlogic and 'oath)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, authentication, twitter

I would like to ask your guidance on how to authenticate using email add/ the basic log-in while having also a twitter log-in, twitter authentication works fine but if having an alternative log-in like using basic sign-up and email log-in part wont work....

any ideas please...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some plugin of authentication like authlogic.

There are several strategie of login.

Answer (score 2):

As [shingara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475691/ruby-on-rails-functionalities-having-twitter-authentication-and-email-authentic/2475736#2475736) mentioned, authlogic is great for authentication, be it email or login based. There's extensions to it such as the [authlogic-oauth](http://github.com/jrallison/authlogic_oauth) plugin/gem which you can use in conjunction with Twitter's OAuth to let users log into your site using their Twitter details.